# Rails Uploading multiple images with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have been following this [tutorial](http://bobintornado.github.io/rails/2015/12/29/Multiple-Images-Uploading-With-CarrierWave-and-PostgreSQL-Array.html) to upload multiple images with carrier wave.

It works as expected but it is displaying the following below the image:

```
[#<ImageUploader:0xaeb3490 @model=#<Post id: 19, created_at: "2017-07-07 09:33:50", updated_at: "2017-07-07 09:33:50", lat: 54.635, long: -5.84582, images: ["87a8c63a9be6af171244299fc0b0a27e--stunning-art-street-art-illusions.jpg"], artist: "Vemeer", year: nil>, @mounted_as=:images, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0xaeb3430 @uploader=#<ImageUploader:0xaeb3490 ...>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0xaeb3100 @file="C:/path/public/uploads/post/images/19/87a8c63a9be6af171244299fc0b0a27e--stunning-art-street-art-illusions.jpg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil>, @versions={}>]
```

As explained in the tutorial to get the multiple uploads I did the following:

**Rails Migration to create array of images:**

```
class AddImagesToGallery < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :images, :string, array: true, default: [] 
  end
end
```

**Edited posts/_form.html.haml:**

```
= f.file_field :images, multiple: true
```

**Edited post_params**

```
def post_params
    post_params.require(:post).permit(:artist, :year, :long, :lat, {images: []})
end
```

**Display the images in posts/show.html.haml**

```
=@mural.images.each do |image|
    = image_tag(image.url)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works as expected but it is displaying the following below the image:

```
[#<ImageUploader:0xaeb3490 @model=#<Post id: 19, created_at: "2017-07-07 09:33:50", updated_at: "2017-07-07 09:33:50", lat: 54.635, long: -5.84582, images: ["87a8c63a9be6af171244299fc0b0a27e--stunning-art-street-art-illusions.jpg"], artist: "Vemeer", year: nil>, @mounted_as=:images, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0xaeb3430 @uploader=#<ImageUploader:0xaeb3490 ...>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0xaeb3100 @file="C:/path/public/uploads/post/images/19/87a8c63a9be6af171244299fc0b0a27e--stunning-art-street-art-illusions.jpg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil>, @versions={}>]
```

This line

```
=@mural.images.each do |image|
    = image_tag(image.url)
```

should be

```
- @mural.images.each do |image|
    = image_tag(image.url)
```

Notice the difference between `=` and `-`. `=` is used to display the output. `-` is used to iterate over the object.

Comment: ah thankyou! I always meant to google what the difference was and now I know